# How to implement decentralized orderer or say peer-org-owned orderer in Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am planning to implement a decentralized orderer or say peer-org-owned orderer in Hyperledger Fabric.

Can someone please explain whether is it valid to implement an orderer from a peer-org-owned organization?

If it's valid then how the configuration will look like?

Answer (score 2):

It is not only valid, but actually encouraged. A decentralized ordering service is the best scenario in HLF, as no single organization has total control over the ordering process. From Fabric v2.3, you can have any organization contribute to the ordering service. They also made it very easy to do so: create an ordering node, and join that ordering node to a channel much like you currently do with your peer nodes. A full tutorial from the Fabric Docs can be found [here](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.3/create_channel/create_channel_participation.html). Take your time when reading through the tutorial as it is quite long and may seem complicated at first.